# JavaScript: code not iterating through questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developing a quiz app in JavaScript and the problem is the questions are not iterating through. In other words, after a user takes the first question by clicking a multiple choice answer and then clicking next button, it does not go to the next question, simultaneously, JS does not recognize I answered the question via `Answer the question!` being the only output from the `if` conditional.

```js
$(function (){
  startQuiz();
  answerResponse();
  answerSubmitted();
  renderQuestionPage();
});

const data = {
  questions:[
// this is object 1 but we won't name it because it is inside an array
{
  question: 'Question 1 what is that thing?',
  answers:[
     'this 1',
     'that 2',
     'something 3',
     'allodat 4'
  ],
  correctAnswer: 'allodat 4'
},
// this is object 2 but we won't name it because it is inside an array
{
  question: 'Question 2 what is that other thing?',
  answers: [
    'bloop',
    'dope',
    'FIRE',
    'HOTZ'
  ],
  correctAnswer: 'dope'
}
],
  currentQuestionIndex: 0,
  totalScore: 0,
  startedQuiz: false,
};



function resetQuiz(){
  data.totalScore = 0;
  data.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
}

function renderQuestionPage() {
  var currentQuestionObj = data.questions[data.currentQuestionIndex];
  renderQuestion();
  renderQuestionOptions(currentQuestionObj.answers);
}

function renderQuestion() {
  var progressHTML = "<span>(" + (data.currentQuestionIndex + 1) +  '/' + data.questions.length + ")</span>"
  var questionText = data.questions[data.currentQuestionIndex].question;
  $(".js-question-text").html(progressHTML + questionText);
  console.log(renderQuestion);
}

function renderQuestionOptions(answers){
  $(".myForm label").each(function(index, label) {
    $(this).find("input").attr("value", answers[index]);
    $(this).find("input").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).find("span").text(answers[index]);
  });
}

function finalResults(){
  $("#questionPage").addClass("hidden");
  $("#results-page").removeClass("hidden");
  $('#retake-button').removeClass("hidden");
  var element = $('.js-final-results');
  element.html("<h2>" + "You got" + '' + data.correctChoice + ' ' + "out of" + ' ' + data.questions.length + ' ' + "correct" + "</h2>");
  retakeQuiz();
}

function checkAnswer(userChoice) {
  var correctChoice = data.questions[data.currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswer;
  console.log(data.currentQuestionIndex, data.questions[data.currentQuestionIndex]);
  if (userChoice === correctChoice) {
    data.totalScore++;
    renderQuestionFeedback(true);
    data.currentQuestionIndex++;
  } else if (userChoice === undefined) {
    renderQuestionFeedback("unanswered");
  } else {
    renderQuestionFeedback(false);
    data.currentQuestionIndex++;
  }
  if (data.currentQuestionIndex == data.questions.length) {
    finalResults();
  } else {
    renderQuestionPage();
  }
}

function renderQuestionFeedback(response){
  var feedback = $(".popup-inner");
  if (response === true) {
    feedback.find("h2").text("That was correct");
  } else if (response === false) {
    feedback.find("h2").text("That was incorrect");
  } else if (response === "unanswered") {
    feedback.find("h2").text("Answer the question!");
  }
}

function startQuiz(){
  $("#startQuiz").click(function(e){
    $("#questionPage").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#startQuiz").addClass("hidden");
    console.log("take quiz clicked");
  });
}

function retakeQuiz(){
  $("#retake-button").click(function(e){
    $("#questionPage").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#retake-button").addClass("hidden");
    resetQuiz();
    renderQuestionPage();
  });
}

function answerSubmitted(){
  $("#submit-answer").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var userChoice = $("input[name='answerChoice']:checked").val();
    renderQuestionFeedback()
    checkAnswer(userChoice);
  });
}

function answerResponse(){
  $("#submit-answer").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetPopupClass = $(this).attr("data-popup-open");
    $(`[data-popup="' + targetPopupClass + '"]`).fadeIn(250);
    e.preventDefault();
    renderQuestionFeedback();
  });
}

function resetQuiz(){
  data.totalScore = 0;
  data.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Brian's Quiz</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="title" role="banner">
        <h1>Brian's Quiz</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <section id="startPage" role="region">
            <h2>Thinkful is in da House!</h2>
            <button type="submit" id="startQuiz" role="button">Start Quiz</button>
        </section>

        <section id="results-page" class="hidden">
            <div class="js-final-results text-center"></div>
            <button class="hidden" id="retake-question"></button>
        </section>

        <section class="popup" data-popup="popup-feedback">
            <div class="popup-inner">
                <h2 id="text-feedback"></h2>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="questionPage" role="region">
            <h3 class="js-question-text">
                <span>(1/10)</span>
            </h3>
            <form class="myForm" action="form" role="form">
                <label class="answer">
                    <input type="radio" name="answerResponse">
                </label>
                <label class="answer">
                    <input type="radio" name="answerResponse">
                </label>
                <label class="answer">
                    <input type="radio" name="answerResponse">
                </label>
                <label class="answer">
                    <input type="radio" name="answerResponse">
                </label>
                <button type="submit" id="submit-answer" data-popup-open="popup-feedback">Next</button>
                <p><span id="questionNo">5</span> out of <span id="outOf">10</span></p>
            </form>
        </section>

        <section id="showAnswer" role="region">
            <h2>Correct</h2>
            <button type="submit" id="continue" role="button">Continue Quiz</button>
        </section>

        <section id="finalPage" role="region">
            <h2>Your Result</h2>
            <p>You got <span id="correctNo">5</span> out of <span id="total-outof">10</span> correct</p>
            <button type="submit" id="retake-button">Retake Quiz</button>
        </section>


    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="quizJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

In the console, when I click the next button, I just get the same question object or question number 1 over and over.

Comment: I tried to do a code snippet, looks like start quiz is not a function.

Comment: @JoshAdams, I had some code missing above. I have added what was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that something is wrong when you compare these lines of code:

`<input type="radio" name="answerResponse">`

and

```
function answerSubmitted(){
  $("#submit-answer").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var userChoice = $("input[name='answerChoice']:checked").val();
    renderQuestionFeedback()
    checkAnswer(userChoice);
  });
}
```

Either your `input name='answerResponse'` or `input name='answerChoice'`

Give it a try.

Comment: thank you, that was it. my questions are now iterating through in the browser.